# How to change the conflict resolution interface in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, merge-conflict-resolution

Some days ago vscode started showing the following interface any time I had a git conflict:

[image: Visual Studio Code interface for git conflict solving]

But I don't like it and want the regular one, the one that looks like this:

[image: Regular interface for conflict solving in vscode]

How can I modify the configurations to change this interface, I've explored hundreds of settings in vscode but haven't found the right one.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: in the settings have you found anything with the term `merge`, also search SO before asking a question, this is about the tenth identical question in last few days

Answer (score 20):

There is a setting called "git.mergeEditor" disable it then you have the old view back !

Comment: Thanks for the info. New `mergeEditor` is unusable IMO.

Comment: I think i will check out some tutorials, 3 way merge seems to be pretty cool if you understand it.

Comment: Maybe, but IMO if you need tutorial on something "visual" then it's badly designed.

Answer (score 3):

@Cristian Diaz Please refer to the latest version (1.71.0) [Release note](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_71#:%7E:text=RESTORING%20OLD%20CONFLICT%20DECORATORS). They didn't remove the old merge conflicts resolution. We can enable it by clicking on the file icon.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore (Version 1.73.1). It just opens the "Incoming" file.